# Is there a difference between [ABCDEFGH] and [A-H] on flex?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have the following code on flex:

```
Y "line "|"triangle "|"square "|"pentagon "|"hexagon "|"heptagon "|"octagon "
X1 [BCDEFGH]*"A"[BCDEFGH]*("A"[BCDEFGH]*)+
X2 [ACDEFGH]*"B"[ACDEFGH]*("B"[ACDEFGH]*)+
X3 [ABDEFGH]*"C"[ABDEFGH]*("C"[ABDEFGH]*)+
X4 [ABCEFGH]*"D"[ABCEFGH]*("D"[ABCEFGH]*)+
X5 [ABCDFGH]*"E"[ABCDFGH]*("E"[ABCDFGH]*)+
X6 [ABCDEGH]*"F"[ABCDEGH]*("F"[ABCDEGH]*)+
X7 [ABCDEFH]*"G"[ABCDEFH]*("G"[ABCDEFH]*)+
X8 [ABCDEFG]*"H"[ABCDEFG]*("H"[ABCDEFG]*)+ 
%%
"point "[ABCDEFGH]{2,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS"); /*check if the letters are more than the given word or shape could have, lines 14-21*/
"line "[ABCDEFGH]{3,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS"); /*if yes,a TOO MANY LETTERS message will appear*/
"triangle "[ABCDEFGH]{4,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"square "[ABCDEFGH]{5,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"pentagon "[ABCDEFGH]{6,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"hexagon "[ABCDEFGH]{7,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"heptagon "[ABCDEFGH]{8,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"octagon "[ABCDEFGH]{9,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");

{Y}({X1}|{X2}|{X3}|{X4}|{X5}|{X6}|{X7}|{X8}) printf("DUPLICATE/S"); /*check if there are any duplicates,if yes,a DUPLICATE message will appear*/

"point "[ABCDEFGH] printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*Here, after we check for duplicates or more letters*/
"line "[ABCDEFGH]{2} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*it will check if the number of letters are EXACTLY as many as they should be*/
"triangle "[ABCDEFGH]{3} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*etc 3 for triangle,8 for octagon, lines 27-32*/
"square "[ABCDEFGH]{4} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*if thats true,it will print the message CORRECT*/
"pentagon "[ABCDEFGH]{5} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
"hexagon "[ABCDEFGH]{6} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
"heptagon "[ABCDEFGH]{7} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
"octagon "[ABCDEFGH]{8} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");

[^\n]+ printf("UNRECOGNIZED CHARACTER/S"); /*show UNRECOGNIZED CHARACTERS if the user tries to write unwanted characters or if he makes an alphabetical mistake*/
%%
int main() {
/*other things*/
}
```

Which checks if the user gave a correct format of a shape expression and prints the corresponding message. for example correct formats are: point A, square AHDB , hexagon HCDBAG
wrong formats are: line AA (duplicate), square ABCDE (more letters)

The problem is, when I replace expressions [ABCDEFGH] with [A-H], the program is working like

```
"point "[ABCDEFGH]{2,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS"); /*check if the letters are more than the given word or shape could have, lines 14-21*/
"line "[ABCDEFGH]{3,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS"); /*if yes,a TOO MANY LETTERS message will appear*/
"triangle "[ABCDEFGH]{4,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"square "[ABCDEFGH]{5,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"pentagon "[ABCDEFGH]{6,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"hexagon "[ABCDEFGH]{7,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"heptagon "[ABCDEFGH]{8,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
"octagon "[ABCDEFGH]{9,} printf("TOO MANY LETTERS");
```

and

```
"point "[ABCDEFGH] printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*Here, after we check for duplicates or more letters*/
"line "[ABCDEFGH]{2} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*it will check if the number of letters are EXACTLY as many as they should be*/
"triangle "[ABCDEFGH]{3} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*etc 3 for triangle,8 for octagon, lines 27-32*/
"square "[ABCDEFGH]{4} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION"); /*if thats true,it will print the message CORRECT*/
"pentagon "[ABCDEFGH]{5} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
"hexagon "[ABCDEFGH]{6} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
"heptagon "[ABCDEFGH]{7} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
"octagon "[ABCDEFGH]{8} printf("CORRECT EXPRESSION");
```

never existed.

For instance:
given "point AB" expression in 1st form ([ABCDEFGH]), will print: TOO MANY LETTERS

given "point A" expression  in 1st form ([ABCDEFGH]), will print: CORRECT EXPRESSION

given "point AB" expression  in 2nd form (if we change [ABCDEFGH] with [A-H]), will print: UNRECOGNIZED
CHARACTER/S.

given "point A" expression in 2nd form (if we change [ABCDEFGH] with [A-H]), will print: UNRECOGNIZED CHARACTER/S.

Is there an explanation why this is occuring?

Comment: **TL;DR** Is this related to C?

Comment: Make sure it is really a simple dash and not a typographic mark like `–`

Comment: If in doubt, copy and paste the precise text into the question. It's always important to show the precise text of the erroneous code.

Comment: the thing is that i have tried [A-H] in another file and it works right

Comment: @nick: that's why you need to share the real code you are having trouble with. You probably introduced some other mistake. But without seeing your code, I can't even guess what it might be. (Make sure you include an entire compilable file which you tested.)

Comment: Also, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66229436/1566221

Comment: The first part is the full flex compilable file.