# Flex/Lex: Regular Expression matches double characters

Tags: c++, c, regex, flex-lexer, lex

I have a flex program written in C++ that needs to complete the following rules: 
I want yytext to accept the following: 
○ Zero or one of the following characters ABCDEFGH
For example - input: 
"triangle ABC" is a valid shape and I want the program to print "Valid shape" 
"triangle AAC" is not a valid shape because it contains a double A and I want the program to print nothing in this case 
"triangle ABCD" is not a valid shape because it contains four letters and I want the program to print nothing in this case too.

The code below and what regular expressions I tried so far:

```
%{
    /** Methods and Variables initialization **/
   
%}

corner corner" "[A-H]
line line" "[A-H]{2}
triangle triangle" "[A-H]{3}
square rectangle" "[A-H]{4}
poly pentagon" "[A-H]{5}
hexa hexagon" "[A-H]{6}
hepta heptagon" "[A-H]{7}
octa octagon" "[A-H]{8}

/** Below is the rule section -- yytext is the matched string returned to the program **/
%%
{corner} 
{line} |
{triangle} |  
{square}  |
{poly} |
{hexa} |
{hepta} | 
{octa} {   
     printf("Valid shape: %s", yytext);
}
.
%%

int main() {
    yylex();    
    return 0;
}

// yywrap() - wraps the above rule section 
int yywrap(void)
{
   return 1;
}
```

The current input:

triangle AAC

The current output:

Valid shape: triangle AAC  (We don't want that)

The current input:

triangle AB

The current output:

Valid shape: triangle ABC

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool to achieve that each of the characters ABC appears only once. Why don't you add an semantic check for this (e.g. in the action of a rule)? In C or C++, such a check is very easy to implement.

Comment: What do you propose?  I need to somehow check for double characters in the matched string (yytext) or something similar.

Comment: Maybe you should get together with @NickGeo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213163/is-there-a-difference-between-abcdefgh-and-a-h-on-flex (perhaps a classmate of yours). Between the two of you, you should be able to complete the assignment :-)

Comment: Also, as I said there, when asking questions of the form "my code doesn't work", it's absolutely necessary to provide a [mre], which is a compilable program (not usually your actual program, but nonetheless a real program which can be made into an executable). You should provide the exact input (if applicable) and explain the exact problem you experience with the program you provided. This is a good exercise whether or not you are asking your question here: the process of reducing irrelevant complications from your program helps you focus on the problem, and often you will find it yourself.

Comment: I edited the title so it can be more focused to the problem and I will go through the link you provided to seek more details of what you are impling.

Comment: Also, @NickGeo has another approach to the same problem but we are not in the same team to cooperate together :)

Comment: @costas_ If it's ok to ask us here, why isn't it ok to ask NickGeo? Or, to put it another way, if you can't cooperate with them, what makes it ok to cooperate with us :-) Anyway, their solution strikes me as reasonable although not particularly scalable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the sort of problem for which you would typically use (f)lex, since the base lexical analysis is trivial (it could be done by simply splitting the line at the space) and detailed error analysis is a bit outside of (f)lex's comfort zone, specifically because there's no way to match "a string containing the same character twice" using a regular expression.

Still, as shown by the [question asked by one of your classmates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213163/is-there-a-difference-between-abcdefgh-and-a-h-on-flex), it can be done with (f)lex by taking advantage of the scanner's ordering rules:

1. Always use the longest possible match.
2. If two or more rules would qualify, choose the first one.

That doesn't get around the question of duplicate characters. The only way to solve that is to enumerate all possibilities, of which there are eight in this case. A simpler way of doing that than that proposed in the linked question is

```
dups [A-H]*A[A-H]*A|[A-H]*B[A-H]*B|[A-H]*C[A-H]*C|[A-H]D*[A-H]D*...`.

That lets you create an ordered set of rules something like this:

1. Match lines with too many characters
2. Match lines with duplicate characters
3. Match lines with exactly the right number of characters
4. Anything else is an error. (Too few characters, invalid shape name, invalid letter, etc.)

So that might include this (leaving out the definitions of the two macros, which is straightforward but tedious):

      /* 1. Dups */
    [a-z]+\ {dups}$  { err("Duplicate letter"); }
      /* 2. Too long */
    {valid}[A-H]+$   { err("Too long"); }
      /* 3. Just right */
    {valid}$         { printf("Valid: %s\n", yytext); }
      /* 4. Anything else */
    .+               { err("Too short or invalid character"); }
      /* Ignore newlines */
    \n               ;
```

Comment: Applying the technique you give as a solution will not work for every single alphabet letter: [A-Z]*A[A-Z]*A[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*B[A-Z]*B[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*C[A-Z]*C[A-Z]*...
It's more than 500 characters line in length and probably it won't fit even in the comment section, here.

Comment: @Vaggelis: The length of the regex is not the only problem if you want to use it for a larger alphabet. Because of the way Flex constructs the state table, the size of the generated scanner is exponential in the size of the alphabet; with `A-H`, it's already 52,563 states, and each additional letter multiplies the state count by about 3.5. That can be fixed by using more precise patterns (which are slightly longer). I'll think about how to fix this answer to reflect all that. I think the question "how do I use really long Flex patterns" is probably worth asking (and answering).

Comment: @VaggelisManousakis; I adjusted the regex by removing the unnecessary final `[A-H]*`; that shortens it enough that you can fit the whole alphabet in 500 characters. It also reduces the state count significantly, but not enough to allow 26 characters; I managed to get up to  the middle of the alphabet but at some point it hits a cliff, which I suppose is a flaw in flex since the slowdown is not linear in the number of states. I'll see if I can write a good answer to your question.